# How to store ruport table data object in a database?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, report, ruport

I intend to store a nightly build of report data in a DB and then use formatters when a user requests for a report in real-time.

A few clues...
The **Ruport::Data::Table** object - that contains the data - is a collection of **Ruport::Data::Record** objects, accessible via the '**data**' attribute i.e.

**Ruport::Data::Table** object

*=> Ruport::Data::Table:0xb6455680 @column_names=[], @record_class="Ruport::Data::Record", @data=[]*

The **Ruport::Data::Record** object contains the **'data' hash** which needs to go into the DB

*Ruport::Data::Record:0x7ff138104c90 @data={}, @attributes=[]*

I'm using Rails and ActiveRecord

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could serialize the content using, for example, `to_yaml`, or use the older [Marshal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Marshal.html).#dump and #load.

I do something similar, although my - relatively simple - data is contained in an OpenStruct. I generate several longer-running reports asynchronously (usually overnight) and retrieve their content from a "cached_reports" table on request.